# Access iFrame content, from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have created the iframe by coding and just append it to current program, after that line I am trying to access and remove the  tag from header inside the iFrame. But it say "DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame". Why this happen? If it is different domain then ok but this is created and append from the same page and program. Any possibility  set permission inside the iframe to allow access from outside.

I am trying below code

```
var all_code="<style>.cs{color:red;}"<\/style>;
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(all_code);
$(".blg_gen_container").css("width",glb_container_width+"px");
$(".blg_gen_container").css("height",glb_container_height+"px");

iframe.height=glb_widget_width+"px";
iframe.height=glb_widget_height+"px";
iframe.id="iframe_rdpostid";
$("#prev_code").empty();
$("#prev_code").append(iframe);

iBody = $('iframe:first').contents().find('body').clone();
```

Comment: The permission is only set on the side that you want to iframe. If you can contact their web admin and add your domain to their access domain pool

Comment: My doubt is I am creating from the same html and append, then why I need this permission? Is this consider as different domain?

Comment: so you mean your iframe and script is on the same domain?

Comment: yes, same. But I am running the program locally without any server.